# How to change image on clicking enter after entering value in textbox?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

There are bunch of images in "assest/image" folder.

We have to see and enter pin code visible in image in textbox.
[image]

Pin Code will be stored in a array created in TypeScript.

On clicking enter after typing pin code

- Next Image should come
- Image No should change
- ImageId should change

Following things should happen until last image comes, on entering enter after last image comes, form should be submitted.

HTML code

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <nav>
       <div class = "navbar-header">
           <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Image Change on clicking Enter in TextBox</a>
           <input class = "col" type = "text" readonly value ="{{imgNumber}}/3  {{cityImageId}}">
       </div>
    </nav>

<div class = "textarea" contenteditable #scrollDiv [scrollTop]="scrollDiv.scrollHeight" wrap="hard">
    <img contenteditable="false" [src]="imagePath" width = "1090px" height = "440"/>
</div>


<form>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" class="col2" [(ngModel)]="city.pinCode" (keyup.enter)="nextImage()" maxlength="6"/>
    </div>
</form>


<div>
    <input type = "label" class = "col3" value = "Pin Code" readonly />
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

TypeScript Code

```
import { CompileEntryComponentMetadata } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CityClassification } from 'src/app/domain/cityClassification.model';
import { CityClassificationService } from 'src/app/service/city-classification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city-classification',
  templateUrl: './city-classification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-classification.component.css']
})
export class CityClassificationComponent implements OnInit {
  imgNumber : number =1;
  cityImageId : number = 101;
  imagePath : string ='assets/images/Ghazipur1.png';
  
 cityDetailArray : CityClassification[] = [];
  
 city: CityClassification = {
   pinCode : '1',
   cityImageId : 101
 }

 nextImage(){}

 constructor(private cityClassificationService: CityClassificationService) { }
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Model Code

```
  export class CityClassification{
  
    pinCode : string;
    cityImageId : number;
   
    constructor(pinCode : string, cityImageId : number){
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.cityImageId = cityImageId;
    }
   
}
```

CSS code

```
nav {
    background-color:black;
    border : 0;
}

.navbar-header{
            text-align: center;
}
.navbar-header{
    color:white;
}
.col{
    margin-left: 950px;
    text-align: right;
    border : 0;
    background-color:rgb(160,0,0);
}

.textarea{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 400px;
    width:1090px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;

     object-fit: none;
     object-position: 1000px 200px;
}

.col2{
    width:230px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 950px;
}

.col3{
    width:230px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 950px;
}
```

My file structure
[image]

GitHub code link = https://github.com/Rajeev-singh-git/cityClassification

Please help me with the code logic, I am stuck from 9 days.

Comment: In What type of condition do you want to change image after enter key being pressed ?

Comment: yes, after entering the value in textbox and pressing enter

Comment: @Rajeev is there any sequence to show next available image ? Or do you want to load any random one image ?

Comment: One image should load only one time, then next Image should come. There is image number associated with image

Comment: GitHub link for code is https://github.com/Rajeev-singh-git/cityClassification

Comment: do you need this https://angular-ivy-bt2lzc.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bt2lzc).

This may be helpful to you.